# Identify all common rows across columns

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet which contains many columns that I'd like to identify all rows which are common across all columns.  Whether this is via highlighting or creation of another column I don't have a preference.  Likewise, formula or macro is equally acceptable.

As an example,

```
--------------------------------------
| List 1 | List 2 | List 3 | List 4  |
--------------------------------------
| Bill   | Carlos | Adam   |  Adam   |
| Carlos | Dan    | Bill   |  Carlos |
| Frank  | Frank  | Carlos |  Frank  |
|        | Gerard | Frank  |  Liam   |
|        |        | Jim    |         |
--------------------------------------
```

In the example above I would like to identify that Carlos and Frank are common across all columns.

Note all the columns are sorted and unique.

I have currently organized the items via a [macro](http://sites.madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/text-functions/line-up-matches) which aligns them across columns.  I assumed from this point it would be easy to highlight all blank rows using [conditional formatting](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45670/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting/) but was not able to accomplish this.  Perhaps I am going at it in the wrong fashion.

The macro code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LineEmUp()
'Author:    Jerry Beaucaire
'Date:      7/5/2010
'Summary:   Line up a random number of columns so all matching
'           items are on the same rows
Dim LC  As Long
Dim Col As Long
Dim LR  As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Spot last column of data
    LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Add new key column  to collect unique values
    Cells(1, LC + 1) = "Key"
    For Col = 1 To LC
        Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(Rows.Count, Col)).SpecialCells(xlConstants).Copy _
           Cells(Rows.Count, LC + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Next Col

    Columns(LC + 1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Cells(1, LC + 2), Unique:=True
    Columns(LC + 2).Sort Key1:=Cells(2, LC + 2), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Fill in new table headers w/formatting
    Range("A1", Cells(1, LC)).Copy Cells(1, LC + 3)

'Fill in new table values
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, LC + 2).End(xlUp).Row
    With Range(Cells(2, LC + 3), Cells(LR, LC + 2 + LC))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC" & LC + 2 & ",C[-" & LC + 2 _
                        & "],0)), RC" & LC + 2 & ", """")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

'Cleanup/Erase old values
    Range("A1", Cells(1, LC + 2)).EntireColumn.Delete xlShiftToLeft
    Columns.Autofit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So what have you done to accomplish this yourself? We're not here to do your job for you - you have to put in at least SOME effort yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I was now required to qualify questions with proof that I've performed appropriate investigation.  I will update.

Comment: no, but until you show  you've put SOME effort into this, we're free to assume "ah yes, someone else wants US to do THEIR job for them".

Comment: Showing your effort does a few things, A) Shows us that you've tried something, and aren't just asking for free solutions/code, B) Shows us your thought process, which can help guide you and show you where you "went wrong", or overlooked something. It's not necessarily just to show "proof" you've done something.  Also, for the record, post your macro code here. I'm (and I assume most others) are very hesitant to click random URLs when Macros are involved.

Comment: Can a name exist only once in each column?

Comment: @Luke Yes, the columns have unique data within them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array formula (use Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering it)

[image]

I used Column C here, but it doesn't matter which column of the set you pick to pull the values from.

As shown Conditional Formatting will also work: use a formula-based rule

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$D$6,A2)=COLUMNS($A$2:$D$6)
```

To apply, select the whole dataset (excluding the headers) and make sure A2 is the Activecell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if list1 is ANYWHERE within list2, you need to put * wildcards on each side of it like this:

```
=If(Iserror(Match("*"&B1&"*",A:A,0)),"False","True")
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a string array with the names of the entire file as its contents.  Then loop through the array for each name, and count the number of times it occurs.  Because the names can only occur once in each column, you can use the occurrences of them in the array to gauge whether it is contained in all columns or not.

If the name has as many occurrences as their are columns in the file, you know that it is contained in all columns.

Hope this gets you started!